# Is there any excel generator that is excel file template based?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I remember that i have seen a project that is generating excel file but it was template based. I mean it was using an excel file that is already have a structure as template.

Do you know such a library for .net ?

Comment: This question doesn't have enough information to be answered. Generally speaking, it is not a problem of the library you are using but of the type of data export you are doing and how you want to interpret the data in the excel template.

Comment: It's not very hard to write one from scratch - you just need an existing Excel file that provides the template and then you need to fill it with data.

Comment: **See** [EPPlus - How to use a template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571581/epplus-how-to-use-a-template)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily read an existing excel file, modify it and write the modified version to the same file or a new one using libs like [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) or [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). We have used both with great success.

Comment: Or just do this using the interop

Comment: Which would require Microsoft Office (with the correct version) being installed on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PowerTools for Open XML](http://powertools.codeplex.com/) , [Creating Pivot table in excel](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2012/01/24/creating-pivot-tables-part-2.aspx)
or you can create the excel file and reflect it using Open xml productivity tool then use the generated code to create the file using Open XML SDK [The Open XML SDK Productivity Tool](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSSMLR19JWA)