# .net docx/xlsx template engine

Tags: .net, ms-office, openxml, template-engine

I need to generate some word/excel documents (invoices, contracts, reports) in .NET application (ASP.NET MVC, if it does matter) from templates. So, is it possible to design template with placeholders and control blocks (i think if and foreach will be enough for my purposes) in word/excel, and then use POCO (or XML, if any xslt-like engines are exists) objects as datasource render documents from temlate? In other words i am trying to find free or opensource word/excel template engine like NVelocity. May be any way to do this with openxml SDK are exists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use Microsoft Office XML. There is both XML format for [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Excel_XML_Spreadsheet_example) and [Word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Word_XML_Format_example). Because it is a normal XML file you could use all .NET stuff for XML's including LINQ to XML, XSLT, string operations etc.

If you cannot use Office XML you could try external libraries like:

- [EPPlus](https://www.epplussoftware.com/) for excel (for more look here: [EPPlus - How to use a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571581/epplus-how-to-use-a-template). Note version 4 of EPPlus is free open source, version 5 is commercial.)
- [docx](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX) for Word

Comment: When i try to save document in single xml (as example for using as NVelocity template), ms office breaks my placeholders into different xml tags, so, i need to edit this xml after each edit of template in msoffice. It is very hard for documents greater 2 pages.

Comment: @Anton unfortunately preparing template is the most time consuming, but you can try docx library, it should help you with preparing templates

Answer (score 0):

You could use the open xml package provided by .Net.
I put a nice wrapper around it for Excel, check my open project:
http://officehelper.codeplex.com/documentation