# Open Excel Template from C# Resource

Tags: c#, excel

I know similar questons have been asked before but cannot find the exact answer I am looking for.

I have an Excel file that I want to use for reporting puropses and populate with lots of results. So I was planning to have an Excel template file as a resource, open it then populate it but it to be left as an unsaved "Book1" workbook. Everything I am reading seems to talk about saving a copy of the resorce file somewhere on the physical disk, but i didn't really want to do this, as I want to leave it up to the user to decide where to save it.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You can open the resource and save it in a temp folder initially.  The user would be free to save it however they want.  Maybe save the temp file with a Guid as its filename.  You can then clean up the temp folder as needed.  There are likely other ways to tackle this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EPPlus - How to use a template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571581/epplus-how-to-use-a-template)

Comment: There are two unrelated questions here: how to create a spreadsheet from a template (use a library like EPPlus) and how to read a resource. As long as the library can read from a stream (EPPlus does) you won't have to save the template to disk

Comment: where in the question does this user reference EPPLus?.....

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out. (tested in .NET 4.5).

```
public void openExcelTemplateFromResources ()
{
    string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName(); 

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath, Properties.Resources.excelResource);

    Excel.Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
    Excel._Workbook excelWorkbook;
    excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(tempPath)

    excelApplication.Visible = true; // at this point its up to the user to save the file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you save a temporary version of the file in the user AppData\Local\ directory. Because in this folder you have always read and write access. After your report is created, you can show a save dialog to decide where to copy your excel-file.

To be sure you use the correct folder, try to use this:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\\YourFolder";
```

Waht do you mean with **Resource**? Do you want to store your report in an assembly?

Comment: The OP asks how to *avoid* saving to disk. There's no reason to if you use a library that reads from a stream instead of accepting just a file name

Comment: You have right. But without knowing which library he use, i can only provide a solution which seems to work in the most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as a resource and extract it into a stream using the following example.  < Namespace > is the namespace of your app, and < FileName > is the actual name of the file.  This will allow you to prompt the user for the save location and then write the stream to disk.

```
Stream stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("<Namespace>.Resources.<FileName>")
```